# FTP Url issue on Mac mini

Tags: mac, osx-lion, ftp, osx-mountain-lion, file-download

We have a few Mac mini OS x 10.8.5 Mountain Lion machines.

One machine is not able to load ftp URL on browsers. Checked terminals (command) also but it is not working.

We have tried firewall and user accounts setting.

For example, the site ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libgcrypt/libgcrypt-1.5.3.tar.bz2.
It is not loading in a browser.

I have checked same network machines ftp sites working fine.

Comment: What error message occurs?

Comment: When you say “checked terminals also but it is not working”, do you mean that you are running an `ftp` command from a command prompt (i.e., shell)? If so, what happens? Are you using anonymous FTP or a real user account? Have you tried connecting to the same server(s) from other (identically configured) machines in your local network?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the FTP Daemon / listener process is running first off.

Then make sure the port is open on the mac Mini server.

Set up the user account and password that can access the server

Attempt the connection.

Please post what you've attempted using screenshots.